# Treenode exist but treenode.nodes.ContainsKey("Nodename") equals false

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

This is my code:

```
if (e.Node.Parent == null)
{
    string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
    TreeNode x = e.Node;
    string response = server.Send_Command(Convert.ToInt32(this.Text), @"browse," + selectedNodeText);
    string[] files = response.Split(',');
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        if (file.Contains(".exe"))
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 1;
            n.Text = file;
            x.Nodes.Add(n);


        }
        else if (file.Contains(".txt") || file.Contains(".doc") || file.Contains(".rtf"))
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 4;
            n.Text = file;
            x.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
        else if (!file.Contains("."))
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 3;
            n.Text = file;
            x.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
        else if (file.Contains(".rar") || file.Contains(".zip"))
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 5;
            n.Text = file;
           x.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
        else if (file.Contains(".sys"))
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 6;
            n.Text = file;
            x.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
            n.ImageIndex = 2;
            n.Text = file;
           x.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
    }
```

Response is comma separated string that contains file names and directories.

Now if I change part of code into:

```
if (file.Contains(".exe"))
{
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
    n.ImageIndex = 1;
    n.Text = file;
    if(treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(file))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        x.Nodes.Add(n);
    }
}
```

It still gives me false and creates new node even if i see that node exists. I check variable file and it is the same as existing node name but it still returns false and creates node.

Comment: `ContainsKey` searches for a `TreeNode` with given `Name`, not `Text`.

Comment: Side note: you can also use `treeView1.Nodes.Find` to search child nodes.

Comment: Thanks for help. Please post it as answear

Comment: You should use `Path.GetExtension` instead of ".Contains()`, because "MyFile.exe.config" is perfectly legal and quite common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [`TreeNodeCollection.ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.1) method documentation:

> Determines whether the collection contains a tree node with the specified key.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The **Name** property corresponds to the key for a **TreeNode** in the **TreeNodeCollection**.

In other words, `ContainsKey` searches for a `TreeNode` with given `Name`, not `Text` as you think.

The same applies to [`IndexOfKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.indexofkey?view=netframework-4.7.1) and [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.1) methods.